# Thrown off by functor syntax in Effective C++

Tags: c++

In Item 15 of Effective C++ 3rd edition an RAII class Font contains as its resource a FontHandle.
The item shows how the Font class can offer an implicit conversion function to its FontHandle thus:

```
operator FontHandle() const 
    {return f;}
```

What is the difference between this code and:

```
FontHandle operator()() const
    {return f;}
```

If there is no difference, is it an unusual and not commonly used syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first, `operator FontHandle`, is a conversion operator.  It allows an instance of this class type to be implicitly converted to a `FontHandle` object, so you could write:

```
Font myFont;
FontHandle handle = myFont;
```

More commonly, conversion operators are used to allow you to use an object of one type as if it were another type in an expression.  For example,

```
void f(FontHandle fh);

Font myFont;
f(myFont); // converts myFont to a FontHandle via the conversion operator
```

The second, `operator()`, is an overload of the function call operator.  It allows an instance of your class type to be used as if it were a function taking no arguments:

```
Font myFont;
myFont();
```

Implicit conversion operators are less common than `operator()` overloads (or, they should be less common).  In many cases they can be very error prone because you have no control over when the operator is used (in C++0x, you'll be able to make conversion operators `explicit` to ensure they are only usable in a few select circumstances).  Whether you want a conversion operator or an `operator()` overload depends on the circumstances, though.

Answer (score 5):

The first provides an implicit conversion, so that you can write

```
FontHandle h = myFont;
```

and also (to be explicit about what's going on)

```
FontHandle h = (FontHandle)myFont;
```

The seconds overloads the function call operator `()`, so that you can write

```
FontHandle h = myFont();
```

Why you'd want the second, I'm not sure. I only have More Effective C++ handy, so I can't check what Meyers says about it.

Comment: From the top of my head, the first syntax also allows an implicit conversion, without the explicit cast.

Comment: My head appears to have the same top as yours. I edited it just before I read your comment.

Comment: `FontHandle h = (FontHandle)myFont;` that's an explicit conversion (via C-style cast). Member `operator X()` methods allows you to do implicit conversions to type X (and make the code that uses it a bit more confusing in the process).